# how to print data in android like the given example

Tags: android

[![image][1]][1]

How to display data  in android like the given below picture

Comment: With code. Be more specific please

Comment: means which view i should use like recyclerview or something.

Comment: What is the format of your data?

Comment: then make a custom view for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

**1st.** Use a single TextView and create the output by using some HTML tags in it, so that it will mach the given example. And then use [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to format it.

**2nd.** Create as many TextViews in your layout as needed, in order to mach the desired UI. Not complicated at all.

Comment: no need to use recyclerView...we can create by using simple textView only?

Comment: Yes. I highly recommend you to find some more info regarding the different types of views in the Android OS and their proper usage.